# Return Max Date for each occurrence of a field

Tags: sql

I need it to return the Max date per city per change, so basically the last day they spend for every visit to a city

I've tried `SELECT userid, city, Max(date) from table group by userid, city`, but it combines separate stays to the same city as as one.

sample table

```
userid  city       date
------  ---------  --------------
Francis Cambridge  06/15/2017
Francis Cambridge  07/01/2017
Francis London     07/02/2017
Francis Cambridge  07/03/2017
Francis NewYork    07/05/2017
Francis NewYork    07/20/2017
Francis NewYork    07/25/2017
Francis London     07/31/2017
```

desired query results

```
userid  city       date
------  ---------  --------------
Francis Cambridge  07/01/2017
Francis London     07/02/2017
Francis Cambridge  07/03/2017
Francis New York   07/25/2017
Francis London     07/31/2017
```

Comment: Which database are you using? is the date column of date type?

Comment: I'm using Oracle and yes its a date type. but I was hoping to get a generic version just in case I need to use it in the future for a different scenario. But I'm happy with Oracle for now.

Comment: is there a primary key in the table?

Comment: there is no primary key

Comment: say if there are two rows for the same user with same date and different cities... how will you know which row to consider first or second?

Comment: I understand what you mean, but in my scenario this is highly unlikely as our protocol only allows one destination per trip per day. This wont be paid for by the company.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `lag` to compare the previous row's userid and city to current row and use a running sum to assign groups based on the specified conditions. Then you just need a `group by` to get the latest date.

```
select userid,city,max(date) 
from (select t.*,sum(col) over(order by date) as grp
      from (select t.*,
            case when lag(userid) over(order by date)=userid 
            and lag(city) over(order by date)=city
            then 0 else 1 end as col
            from tbl t
           ) t
      ) t 
group by userid,city,grp
```

Comment: or use [Tabibitosan method](http://rwijk.blogspot.in/2014/01/tabibitosan.html) - which has one less level of subquery

Comment: thanks vkp I will try out your solution and will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

So, you want the stays that there is not a subsequent stay at the given city

calling the table stay_log:

`select userid, city, date 
 from stay_log last_date
 LEFT JOIN stay_log next_date ON 
    last_date.userid = next_date.userid and
    last_date.city = next_date.city and 
    DateAdd(last_date, "1", 1) = next_date.date
 WHERE next_date.userid is null`

Comment: thanks Rob Conklin I will try out your solution and will get back to you